# Thread.sleep and repainting

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, repaint

I have a panel that displays text. I want the panel to change its text and then have the application pause before anything else happens. I'm using Thread.sleep(1000). For some reason, though, the application doesn't finish painting the panel before Thread.sleep gets called (the text doesn't get changed). I also tried this:

```
board.invalidate();
board.setLeftMessage("Not");
board.setRightMessage("Here");
board.revalidate();
Date current = new Date();
long timeNow = current.getTime();
Date newDate = new Date(timeNow + 1000);
while (current.before(newDate))
    current = new Date();
```

but no luck there either. Anyone have a suggestion?
Thanks so much.

Comment: Don't block the main thread, ever.

Answer (score 8):

You are blocking the AWT Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). The EDT handle repainting and input events, so your code need not be multithreaded (which would be effectively impossible). Use `javax.swing.Timer` to send an event later on the EDT. (Do not confuse `javax.swing.Timer` with `java.util.Timer`!)

Comment: Wow - even though, you said - "don't confuse" I still managed to do so. Should have made that one bold ;)

Comment: @javamonkey79 I actually added that bit after I saw your answer. (Stack Overflow gives a five minute window in which edits don't appear in the history.)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at `javax.swing.Timer` - I think this is what you'll need to accomplish this.

EDIT #1: The Sun\Oracle documentation actually suggests using Swing Timers from [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

> In general, we recommend using Swing
>   timers rather than general-purpose
>   timers for GUI-related tasks because
>   Swing timers all share the same,
>   pre-existing timer thread and the
>   GUI-related task automatically
>   executes on the event-dispatch thread.
>   However, you might use a
>   general-purpose timer if you don't
>   plan on touching the GUI from the
>   timer, or need to perform lengthy
>   processing.

EDIT #2: It looks like there are some good basic tutorials [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Timer.htm).

EDIT #3: Removed suggestion of using TimerTask - in this case it would be a bad idea.

Comment: If you use `TimerTask` you'll be off the EDT, and hence in danger.

Comment: @Tom - how so? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I tried TimerTask with no luck too. But how can I schedule a pause in swing timer? What can I put in the actionPerformed method to make the program stop? If I schedule the task at a delay, the rest of the program will still continue to run.

Comment: @rach You put all the code you want to execute after the delay in the actionPerformed implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Your "long running task" needs to run in a separate Thread. Then when you want to update the GUI you need the code to run on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). Then you can ask the separate Thread to sleep and it won't affect the painting of the GUI.

You should be able to use a SwingWorker for this. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.

If you don't like using the SwingWorker, then you need to create your own Thread and wrap the code that updates the GUI in a SwingUtilities.invokeLater().

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be updating GUI components from your main thread. Use [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to schedule your update on the event thread:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    board.invalidate();
    board.setLeftMessage("Not");
    board.setRightMessage("Here");
    board.revalidate();
  }
};
```

Comment: But you can't really set this to run on an interval though, right?

Comment: @javamonkey79: This is just for the GUI update. The OP can still use `Thread.sleep` after this.

Answer (score 1):

`Thread.sleep` is a long running task. When you a running such a task in the EDT it blocks all repaint requests from being executed. All repaint requests which are pending and which were sent during the sleep phase are queued for future processing.

As a result when the EDT comes out of the `sleep` phase it coalesce all such repaint request (if coalescing is enabled which is the default property) into a single repaint which gets executed. If coalescing is not enabled then all queued request are executed serially without any time gap in between. As a result it seems that the UI did not update.

To correct the situation use a `timer` which triggers periodically after specific intervals of time.