# Disable a JButton on click and re-enable it 1 second later?

Tags: java, swing

I need to disable a JButton on on click and enable it again 2 seconds later, so for I've tried sleeping the ui thread from the event handler, but that leaves the button in a selected state where you can't read the text of the disabled button.

The code looks something like this:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Press me");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        JButton button = ((JButton)e.getSource());
        button.setEnabled(false);
        button.setText("Wait a second")
        button.repaint();
        try {
           Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        }
        button.setEnabled(true);
        button.setText("");
    }
```

What happens is the button remains in a "being selected" state with no text for the 2 seconds and instantly disables and re-enables the button at the end, which isn't what I want, what I'm aiming for is the button to stay in a disabled state with text on it for two seconds and then re-enable.

What do I do?

Comment: Don't use Thread.sleep on the UI thread (the UI "freezes" and *does not have a chance to repaint*). Use a Timer. There are many duplicates.

Comment: Did you try disabling any button that had text in it outside of any event or timer code to confirm that it produces the effect you want under any circumstances?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348962/thread-sleep-and-repainting , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18164944/actionlistener-and-thread-sleep , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074329/using-sleep-for-a-single-thread , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652914/thread-sleep-stopping-my-paint

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [user2864740](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2864740/user2864740) indicated - "*Don't use Thread.sleep on the UI thread (the UI "freezes" and does not have a chance to repaint). Use a Timer class.*"

Here's an example of the kind of thing he was referring to. Should be close to what you want to do:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Press me");
int delay = 2000; //milliseconds
Timer timer = new Timer(delay, new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        button.setEnabled(true);
        button.setText("");
    }
});
timer.setRepeats(false);
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        JButton button = ((JButton)e.getSource());
        button.setEnabled(false);
        button.setText("Wait a second")
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Faceplanted read the javadoc of javax.swing.Timer. In the actionPerformed method, disble the button, and start a timer that will reenable it 1 second later.

Comment: On stack exchange meta there was a discussion and the consensus was to plagiarize comments and put them into answers. I'm not kidding. But sure, I'll cobble together an example.

Comment: @user2864740 thanks for your input.  I did some legwork to make the answer more complete.

Comment: @1sand0s Thanks, that is better. I really am flattered that my comment was used at the start (don't need to link me!) but I don't like too-short answers! A reference or two - JB Nizet has a good suggestion - would help round out the details.

Comment: @user2864740 I'm not totally sure what he means but if someone edits it in, I'll accept the changes.

Comment: @1sand0s You must start the Timer. Not just construct it. And you must make sure it doesn't execute every 2 seconds, ad vitam aeternam. And button.repain() is useless.

Comment: @JBNizet Yup. OK did it. Should be close now?